# Filesystem performance issue with lots of sub-directories for attachments

Tags: file, gitlab, filesystems, self-hosting, gitlab-ce

all the attachments from issues are put into a @hashed directory. Each attachment creates its own hashed directory. Over time it can create a lot of sub-directories in a single directory. A project with 100K issues with an average 10 images each can lead to 1 million. This can be a performance bottleneck. How does Gitlab suggest self hosting users do for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer here https://forum.gitlab.com/t/filesystem-performance-issue-with-lots-of-sub-directories-for-attachments/76004

Basically quoting @gitlab-greg from the gitlab forum

Usually bottlenecks are caused by excessive read/write operations where input/output is the limiting factor. Attachments usually take up minimal storage space, so it’s actually much easier and more common for someone to hit max I/O by downloading/pushing a lot of Git Repo, LFS, or (Package|Container) Registry data in parallel. Alternatively, if storage space is filled up (90%+ full), you might see some performance issues.

I’ve not heard of any situations where the existence of high number of image uploads or a large amount of sub-directories in @hashed directory has caused a performance bottleneck in itself. GitLab uses a database to keep track of where issue attachments are stored, so it’s not like it’s crawling or looking through every directory in @hashed every time an upload or image is requested.

I’ve worked with GitLab admins who have (tens of) thousands of users and I’ve never seen subdirectories for attachments result in a performance bottleneck. If you find it does cause a bottleneck, please create an issue.